# Вывод определённых данных из строки при помощи RedBean

Tags: php, mysql, redbeanphp, steam

Как при помощи ORM RedBean вывести определённые данные?
У меня есть таблица, которая называется "users", в ней есть 3 столбца:
 `"id", "steamid" и "balance"`
 Первая строка выглядит примерно так: 
 `id: 1; steamid: 123..0; balance: 1337`
 Как мне сделать так, чтобы на сайте выводился только баланс пользователя с steamid 123..0?

Comment: Вам прошлый раз помогли, было несколько примеров запроса в БД. Почему же Вы не учитесь? Не говоря уже о том, что не отметили предыдущую Вам помощь? Приложите пример того, как Вы пытались реализовать запрос сами.

Comment: Как учится? Того, что мне нужно почти не найти. "Не говоря уже о том, что не отметили предыдущую Вам помощь?" - Я недавно зарегистрировался на StackOverflow и ещё не разобрался что тут да как.

Comment: Информации в интернете много Вот несколько: 1. https://redbeanphp.com/index.php?p=/tutorial  2. https://prowebmastering.ru/redbeanphp-orm-dlya-php.html 3. https://www.sitepoint.com/introduction-redbean/

Answer (score 0):

```
//Подключаем библиотеку
require 'rb.php';
// Подключаемся к БД.
R::setup( 'mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=redbean','login', 'password' ); 
// Проверяем соединение с БД.
if ( !R::testConnection() )
{
        exit ('Нет соединения с базой данных');
}
//Ищем, есть ли данные в базе с таким SteamID
$book = R::find('users', 'steamid LIKE ' . $profilesteamid); // Где $profilesteamid - параметр steamID по поторому найдо найти запись.
// Получаем id записи с таким SteamID)
$GetSteamID = key($book);

$book = R::load('users', $GetSteamID); //Загружаем данные по идентификатору
echo $book->balance; //Выводим данные из столбца баланс. 
$BalanceSumm = $book->balance; //Записываем в переменную
```

Comment: Кстати, Вы тогда писали про то, что можно "отмечать" ответы, как это сделать?

Comment: Это я просто вредничаю. Если данное решение Вам помогло и Вы считаете его корректным - Вы можете отметить слева от ответа галочкой (Если данный ответ решает Вашу задачу) и стрелочкой вверх (Если считаете это решение правильным)